# Problema com acentos, execução no Prompt do Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, acentuação

Estou criando um software em `Python`, estou com problemas no acento das strings.

O programa é simples.. Ele faz uma perguntas para o usuário (nome, versão, descrição, etc) E adiciona as respostas dessas perguntas no meio de um arquivo de texto.. No fim ele exibe o conteúdo do arquivo de texto para o usuário copiar.

Porém ao exibir, os acentos não ficam direitinhos.. Vou deixar um `print` do erro pra vocês verem... Já tentei colocar u antes do arquivo e até mesmo nos input para testar e mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Dei um `sys.getdefaultencoding()` no arquivo para saber qual o formato e é `utf-8`.

Já tentei colocar:

- `# -- coding: UTF-8 --`
- `# -- coding: iso-8859-1 --`
- `#-- coding: latin-1 --`
- `-- coding: CP850 --`

[ERRO http://www.imgfans.com.br/i777/SirGates/erro.png](http://www.imgfans.com.br/i777/SirGates/erro.png).

Comment: Desde o Python 3 não há necessidade de prefixar a *string* com o caractere `u`, qualquer *string* já é criada usando o [unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html). Você está especificando a codificação de maneira errada, o certo é: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: O problema esta no *prompt* do Windows. De acordo com o trecho extraído [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17177904/4336024) no SOEn: Caracteres unicodes só serão exibidos se a fonte atual do *console* conter o caractere. Utilize uma fonte *TrueType*, como Lucida Console.

Comment: [Solução relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/300379/como-imprimir-caracteres-utf-8-na-console-c/300387#300387)

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você está se referindo ao console do Windows, ou `cmd.exe`.

Por padrão, o `cmd.exe` não trabalha com o *encoding* de saída `UTF-8`, também conhecido como a [`Code Page`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) de código [`65001`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Code_page_65001).

Para alterá-la, basta digitar o comando no console:

```
chcp 65001
```

Alternativamente você pode iniciar o console já com o *encoding* de saída ajustado para `UTF-8`, vejamos:

**1)** Pressione <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>;

**2)** Execute o seguinte comando:

```
cmd.exe /K chcp 65001
```