# Como imprimir caracteres UTF-8 na console c++?

Tags: c++, utf-8, console

O console mostra incorretamente caracteres acentuados.
Como imprimi-los corretamente (UTF-8)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1º declarar a biblioteca: `#include <locale.h>`
2º colocar no inicio da função main:
`setlocale(LC_ALL,"");` `// Este comando pega a codificação da maquina que está rodando.`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>    
using namespance std;
int main(){

setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

cout <<"Acento é legal =D "<< endl;

}
```

Comment: Seria melhor uma resposta em C++, devido a tag [tag:c++] da pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade foi a resposta mais simples e eficiente, resolveu o problema com apenas 2 linhas de código.

Comment: Esse código ajusta o seu programa ao "encoding" do console, e nada garante que você vai estar trabalhando com um console em `UTF-8` (assim como mencionado na pergunta). Ah! ["Idioma" não é "encoding"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281646/whats-the-difference-between-encoding-and-charset)!

Comment: @RogérioDec, discordo, essa resposta não resolve o seu problema de poder usar UTF-8.

Comment: @Mário Feroldi, Para mim resolveu, porque minha pergunta é: "Como imprimir caracteres UTF-8 na console c++?". E com essas duas linhas, os caracteres acentuados aparecem na console. Para que complicar?

Comment: @RogérioDec, desculpe-me por soar rude. Por essa resposta, o console não está usando UTF-8 como encoding, e sim o atual do Windows, mudando apenas o idioma. É uma diferença técnica, mas muito importante e que pode acabar gerando confusão futuramente.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Estou feliz de te-lo  ajudado. Aos demais, primeiramente obrigado pelas criticas, até então não sabia a diferença entre: codificação de  caracteres e conjunto de caracteres, como já perceberam meu conhecimento é básico, mas gosto de compartilhar o pouco que sei. Abraço a todos.

Comment: @Mário Feroldi, preciso dar o braço a torcer. Tive que lançar uma pergunta aqui para entender por que um simples `stof("1.9")` trazia apenas `1` e não `1.9`. Daí descobri que `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")` muda inclusive o sistema de numeração para o padrão brasileiro, ou seja, ponto vira vírgula. Maior confusão por causa deste comando...

Answer (score 4):

Provavelmente você está se referindo ao console do Windows, ou `cmd.exe`.

Por padrão, o `cmd.exe` não trabalha com o *encoding* de saída `UTF-8`, também conhecido como a [`Code Page`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) de código [`65001`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Code_page_65001).

Para alterá-la, basta digitar o comando no console:

```
chcp 65001
```

Alternativamente você pode iniciar o console já com o *encoding* de saída ajustado para `UTF-8`, vejamos:

**1)** Pressione <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>;

**2)** Execute o seguinte comando:

```
cmd.exe /K chcp 65001
```

Segue um programa em `C++` capaz de testar se o console foi configurado corretamente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>


int main(){

    setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );

    std::wstring ch = L"你好世界";
    std::wstring gk = L"γειά σου κόσμος";
    std::wstring jp = L"こんにちは世界";
    std::wstring ko = L"여보세요 세계";
    std::wstring pt = L"Olá mundo!";
    std::wstring ru = L"Здравствулте мир!";

    std::wcout << L"Chinês    : " << ch << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Grego     : " << gk << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Japonês   : " << jp << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Coreano   : " << ko << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Português : " << pt << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Russo     : " << ru << std::endl;

}
```

Saída:

```
Chinês    : 你好世界
Grego     : γειά σου κόσμος
Japonês   : こんにちは世界
Coreano   : 여보세요 세계
Português : Olá mundo!
Russo     : Здравствулте мир!
```

**Referências:**

chcp: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp

Comment: Obrigado. Você saberia dizer como poderia fazer para automatizar isto na console do Visual Studio 2017? Ou seja, na hora de abrir a console pelo VS, já teria esta configuração?